# How to display data from a query to a view in mvc in a vertical format?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, html-table, row

I'm currently getting the results to display like this

Col 1 Col 2 Col 3 
1     Ava   Marie 
 
2    Ashley  Lee

But I'd like to display it like this:

1       2 
Ava     Ashley 
Marie     Lee

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Col 1 </th>
            <th>Col 2 </th>
            <th>Col 3 </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.ID<td/>
                <td>@item.FirstName</td>
                <td>@item.LastName</td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```